# Option "inter-unit-product" not working in siunitx package

Tags: siunitx

I am unable to insert a `\cdot` between the units when using the `siunitx` package.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}}
\begin{document}
What I Get:
\qty{12.5}{\meter\per\second}\par
What I want:
12.5 m\ensuremath{\cdot}s\textsuperscript{--1}.
\end{document}
```

The corresponding output is:

[image: Output.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing in text mode, so `siunitx` replaces `\cdot` by `\textperiodcentered`. However, you've added `\ensuremath`, and we then end up with an invalid siltation (and a warning in the log). The easiest fix is to remove the `\ensuremath` part. If you want to keep that, you'll need to make a copy of `\cdot` that `siunitx` is not 'looking' for:

```latex
\NewCommandCopy\mycdot\cdot
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\mycdot}}
```

Comment: This works. Thank you.